# ASP.NET Core MVC Loading Session Asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been reading the official [Session and application state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state) documentation and have stumbled upon the following paragraph:

> **Loading Session asynchronously**
>
> The default session provider in ASP.NET Core loads the session record
>   from the underlying *IDistributedCache* store asynchronously only if the
>   *ISession.LoadAsync* method is explicitly called before the *TryGetValue*,
>   *Set*, or *Remove* methods. If *LoadAsync* is not called first, the
>   underlying session record is loaded synchronously, which could
>   potentially impact the ability of the app to scale.
>
> To have applications enforce this pattern, wrap the
>   *DistributedSessionStore* and *DistributedSession* implementations with
>   versions that throw an exception if the *LoadAsync* method is not called
>   before *TryGetValue*, *Set*, or *Remove*. **Register the wrapped versions in
>   the services container**.

The wrapping itself is not an issue for me, but in order to implement it, I need:

1. Reference to the original implementation
2. Registering the wrapped version

Currently, I have created the following wrapper class:

```
public class WrappedDistributedSession : ISession
  {
    private DistributedSession _service;
    private bool loaded = false;

    public WrappedDistributedSession(DistributedSession service)
    {
      _service = service;
    }

    public bool IsAvailable => _service.IsAvailable;

    public string Id => _service.Id;

    public IEnumerable<string> Keys => _service.Keys;

    public void Clear() => _service.Clear();

    public Task CommitAsync() => _service.CommitAsync();

    public Task LoadAsync()
    {
      loaded = true;
      return _service.LoadAsync();
    }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
      if(loaded)
      {
        _service.Remove(key);
      } else
      {
        throw new Exception();
      }
    }

    public void Set(string key, byte[] value)
    {
      if (loaded)
      {
        _service.Set(key, value);
      }
      else
      {
        throw new Exception();
      }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out byte[] value)
    {
      if (loaded)
      {
        return _service.TryGetValue(key, out value);
      }
      else
      {
        throw new Exception();
      }
    }
  }
```

And I have registered it in the `Startup.ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddScoped<ISession, WrappedDistributedSession>();
```

Obviously, since I am writing this question, my solution does not work. Where did I go wrong and how does one "*Register the wrapped versions in the services container*"?

Comment: Do you still have the `AddSession` call? And more importantly: do you register your implementation before of after AddSession? It's important, because most `AddXxx` classes use a `TryAddcoped|Transient|Singleton` instead of `AddScoped|Transient|Singleton` so it must be registered before.

Comment: Instead of implementing `ISession`, define your own application-specific abstraction. This abstraction can me small (preferably one member) and tailored for your application's needs. If you do this, you'll considerably simplify your implementation and you don't even have to "throw an exception if the LoadAsync method is not called before TryGetValue", because you'll prevent this from happening inside your own session implementation. If you do this, you'll effectively follow both the Dependency Inversion Principle and Interface Segregation Principle.

Comment: @Steven: so instead of using `ISession`, I should write my own layer that calls `LoadAsync` for me? But how about if I access the session via `HttpContext.Session` where I have a direct reference to the `ISession`? I am not the only developer on this project and would really prefer a bullet-proof solution.

Comment: @alesc: I'm not talking about layers here. I'm just talking defining your  own interface and placing that on the 'adapter' implementation you already have. This adapter can be placed in or near your Composition Root and at that point you have access to everything specific to ASP.NET, such as the `HttpContext`. So your adapter can just call `HttpContext.Session` in the proper manner.

Comment: @Steven it is good to give an answer and this often it leads to a solution. You did not give nearly enough information to show how to do what was asked, to Register the wrapped version. You seem to be asking us to go learn how to code the way you believe to be the proper style. I am like the questioner. It doesn't work and I don't know why. Admittedly Microsoft should have examples in their docs but alas they do not. So here we are. If you know how, please post a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use at your risk. This seems to work in Configure method just after sessions.
This solution is an adaptation from this unit test:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/cd0eab88eaa230fa276c27ab5dc71ea267efe14f/src/Middleware/Session/test/SessionTests.cs#L654-L656

```
 app.UseSession();
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
 {
    await context.Session.LoadAsync();
    await next();
 });
```

Or as a more qualified wrapper extension:

```
public static class SesssionAsyncExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Have sessions be asyncronous. This adaptation is needed to force the session provider to use async calls instead of syncronous ones for session. 
    /// Someone surprisingly for something that seems common, Microsoft didn't make this aspect super nice.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">App builder instance.</param>
    /// <returns>App builder instance for chaining.</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// From Microsoft Documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0):
    /// The default session provider in ASP.NET Core will only load the session record from the underlying IDistributedCache store asynchronously if the
    /// ISession.LoadAsync method is explicitly called before calling the TryGetValue, Set or Remove methods. 
    /// Failure to call LoadAsync first will result in the underlying session record being loaded synchronously,
    /// which could potentially impact the ability of an application to scale.
    /// 
    /// See also:
    /// https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d2a0cbc093e1e7bb3e38b55cd6043e4e2a0a2e9a/src/Middleware/Session/src/DistributedSession.cs#L268
    /// https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/1840#issuecomment-454182594
    /// https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2019/12/aspnet-core-load-session-state.html
    /// </remarks>
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseAsyncSession(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSession();
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await context.Session.LoadAsync();
            await next();
        });
        return app;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to implement `ISessonStore` too (which is actually mentioned in the documentation you quoted), as it's the only one registered in `AddSession` extension method.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSession(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (services == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    services.AddTransient<ISessionStore, DistributedSessionStore>();
    services.AddDataProtection();
    return services;
}
```

`ISessionStore` (and hence `DistributedSessionStore`) has a `Create` (see [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/DistributedSessionStore.cs#L32-L44)) method which returns `ISession`. Here you need to return your custom implementation.

https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/SessionServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27-L29

Then you can add before `AddSession` with

```
services.AddTransient<ISessionStore, AsyncDistributedSessionStore>();
```

Comment: Currently I have not implemented the `ISessonStore` since I did not not how. So basically I have to rewrite both classes so that the wrapped version will be used. Do I still need `AddSession` in this case, since I already register everything manually?

Comment: `ISessionStore` is just a factory with a single `Create` method.See the default distributed session implementation here https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/DistributedSessionStore.cs. `ISession` is not resolved via DI but via this factory method

Comment: None of these apply to .NET Core 2.0. I cannot find a sample anywhere where the recommended pattern is detailed, listen up Microsoft!